I migrated from one cpanel hosting to another cpanel and the crm stopped working
I'm new here and I need help, I migrated a website + CRM from a cpanel hosting to another cpanel. the website works great, but the CRM (domain/admin), error 500 appears.
Can you help me please, I'm not comfortable working with backend
I've already changed new names and users in the database, but it still doesn't appear, is it because I changed the domain DNS?
my logs:
[Thu Jun 20 15:47:03.228284 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 577658:tid 23081320904448] [remote 82.155.123.13:51048] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/pznqutss/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php8,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Thu Jun 20 15:47:02.045709 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 577658:tid 23081310398208] [remote 82.155.123.13:51048] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/pznqutss/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php8,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Thu Jun 20 15:47:00.957687 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 577658:tid 23081304094464] [remote 82.155.123.13:51048] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/pznqutss/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php8,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Thu Jun 20 15:46:58.025890 2024] [autoindex:error] [pid 577658:tid 23081291486976] [remote 82.155.123.13:51048] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /home/pznqutss/public_html/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.php,index.php8,index.php7,index.php5,index.perl,index.pl,index.plx,index.ppl,index.cgi,index.jsp,index.jp,index.phtml,index.shtml,index.xhtml,index.html,index.htm,index.js) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
[Wed Jun 19 19:01:11.460460 2024] [security2:error] [pid 3689808:tid 23081187735296] [client 138.68.82.23:37164] [client 138.68.82.23] ModSecurity: Warning. Pattern match "(?i)\\\\b(?:s(?:e(?:t(?:_(?:e(?:xception|rror)_handler|magic_quotes_runtime|include_path)|defaultstub)|ssion_s(?:et_save_handler|tart))|qlite_(?:(?:(?:unbuffered|single|array)_)?query|create_(?:aggregate|function)|p?open|exec)|tr(?:eam_(?:context_create| ..." at ARGS:<?php $env["USERNAME"] . [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/imunify360-full-apache/013_i360_infectors.conf"] [line "86"] [id "77134464"] [msg "IM360 WAF: Infectors: PHP Injection High-Risk PHP Function||T:APACHE||SC:/home/pznqutss/public_html/php-cgi"] [severity "DEBUG"] [tag "service_im360"] [hostname "ammaclinic.pt"] [uri "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"] [unique_id "ZnMc5_D-YzXp_kjOfvEsfAAAAAc"]
[Wed Jun 19 19:01:11.455601 2024] [security2:error] [pid 3689808:tid 23081187735296] [client 138.68.82.23:37164] [client 138.68.82.23] ModSecurity: Warning. Match of "rx \\\\/wc-api\\\\/KCO_WC_Validation\\\\/" against "REQUEST_URI" required. [file "/etc/apache2/conf.d/modsec_vendor_configs/imunify360-full-apache/006_i360_custom.conf"] [line "29"] [id "77140164"] [msg "IM360 WAF: PHP Injection Low value||T:APACHE||SC:/home/pznqutss/public_html/php-cgi"] [severity "DEBUG"] [tag "service_im360"] [hostname "ammaclinic.pt"] [uri "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"] [unique_id "ZnMc5_D-YzXp_kjOfvEsfAAAAAc"] 


The two bottom lines are about modsec freaking out about something security-related, and the top four lines are about a missing index file. How did you perform this migration? Have you tried contacted your new host?

I did the migration, downloading the public html files from cpanel and the databases

I didn't make contact, I just purchased the new accommodation

That looks like the Apache error log. Is there anything in the PHP error log?
